# What Causes Websites To Give An Error Message When Submitting Information

Tags: php

I tried submitting documents and a an upload photo in a certain website and I got this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Trying to access
> array offset on value of type null Filename: helpers/common_helper.php
> Line Number: 13 Backtrace: File:
> /home5/royalear/public_html/application/helpers/common_helper.php
> Line: 13 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: /home5/royalear/public_html/application/views/pages/whatsapp.php
> Line: 20 Function: showFlash
>
> File: /home5/royalear/public_html/application/views/layouts/common.php
> Line: 9 Function: view
>
> File: /home5/royalear/public_html/application/controllers/Member.php
> Line: 781 Function: view
>
> File: /home5/royalear/public_html/index.php Line: 315 Function:
> require_once
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null
>
> Filename: helpers/common_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 13
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
> /home5/royalear/public_html/application/helpers/common_helper.php
> Line: 13 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: /home5/royalear/public_html/application/views/pages/whatsapp.php
> Line: 20 Function: showFlash
>
> File: /home5/royalear/public_html/application/views/layouts/common.php
> Line: 9 Function: view
>
> File: /home5/royalear/public_html/application/controllers/Member.php
> Line: 781 Function: view
>
> File: /home5/royalear/public_html/index.php Line: 315 Function:
> require_once
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null
>
> Filename: helpers/common_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 13
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
> /home5/royalear/public_html/application/helpers/common_helper.php
> Line: 13 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: /home5/royalear/public_html/application/views/pages/whatsapp.php
> Line: 20 Function: showFlash
>
> File: /home5/royalear/public_html/application/views/layouts/common.php
> Line: 9 Function: view
>
> File: /home5/royalear/public_html/application/controllers/Member.php
> Line: 781 Function: view
>
> File: /home5/royalear/public_html/index.php Line: 315 Function:
> require_once

The photo is a screenshot,,,where is the problem??

Comment: Don't post ALLCAPS, it's considerer shouting/rude

Comment: the reason you see this is likely change of PHP version and/or configuration, causing things previously left unreported now being reported as errors.